# XSL transform nDash to question mark. Why?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I've encountered a problem that I need some help solving.

Whenever I open my XSLT file, the nDash character is replaces with a question mark. I've looked all over the internet for an answer but never got one.

However, here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="actionResponse"/>
    <xsl:template match="userData">    
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="./userAttributes[fieldId='1042']/value='–'">
                <xsl:text>-</xsl:text> 
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>    
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As you see, I have encoding = "UTF-8" which SHOULD support nDash.

But instead the nDash value get replaced with a "?".

Why?

Comment: Probably because the file isn't actually encoded in UTF-8, but in some other encoding (e.g Windows-1252). If your file is in an encoding different from the one it declares itself to use, the parser is going to misread it.

Comment: "*Whenevery I open my XSLT file*" Open it using what?

Comment: @michael.hor257k Using notepad++ or just a simple notepad

Comment: How do you run the XSLT transformation?

Comment: When you open it in Notepad++, which encoding has the tick against it in the Encoding menu?